# Isolating element on webpage using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I created a Firefox add-on for myself to view the button at http://www.reddit.com/r/thebutton. <strike>All I want is for the button to be the only element shown.</strike>  All I want is for the button form to be the only form shown.  This is the only way I could find to isolate the button using jQuery. I feel like its the wrong way to do it and was curious if there was a proper way.

```
$('#header').remove();
$('.side').remove();
$('.footer-parent').remove();
$('#siteTable').remove();
$('#progressIndicator').remove();
$('.debuginfo').remove();
$('section').remove();
$('.content').css({"margin" : "auto"});
```

Comment: Well if it's for yourself then as long as it works then it is good to go. You can also do `.hide()` on the elements and should produce the same result

Comment: I was just thinking if they added one extra section to the page I would have to go back and add a new hide line and it seems wrong to have to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
$('.thebutton-form').prependTo('body');
$('body').children().not('.thebutton-form').hide(); // or remove()
```

This will attach the button to the beginning of the document and hide or remove the rest of the stuff

This solution does not depend on the `#header` being there.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
$('body').prepend($('.thebutton-form'));
$('body').children(':not(.thebutton-form)').hide();
```

You could also use `.remove();`.

BTW not entirely sure if it is cross browser or not.

First line moves the form to be a direct child of the body. Second line hides / removes all other elements in the body that are not the form.

No idea why i used insertAfter instead of prepend /append but I fixed it.

Comment: Actually, what you posted before

    $('.thebutton-form').insertBefore('#header');
    $('body').children(':not(.thebutton-form)').hide();

worked but when I try this one all it does is have the words ".thebuttonform" in the panel.

Comment: Yea I forgot to do `.prepend($('.thebutton-form'));`. I corrected my solution